# How does javax.websocket.Session.isOpen() method work?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, tyrus

Let's suppose we have open websocket between client and javaee server. There is a method session.isOpen() which can be used to check if session is still open. But what will return this method and why if client computer suddenly will be switched off or the user left the page but our js script didn't close the connection. How reliable is this method?

Comment: Please let me know if my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38200422/1426227) works for you.

Comment: @Cássio Mazzochi Molin Thank you for your comment. However, I can take a look maybe in a week or in a month. However, I will try not to forget.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

When the user leaves the page, the browser is supposed to close any WebSockets connections. Hence, the [`Session#isOpen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#isOpen--) method should return `false`.

You always can use the [`Session#setMaxIdleTimeout(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#setMaxIdleTimeout-long-) method to set the number of milliseconds before the session be closed by the container if it is inactive (no messages are either sent or received). It's useful when the browser do not close the connections as expected.

### Long answer

The current HTML Live Standard defines the following regarding [unloading documents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#unloading-documents:make-disappear):

> This specification defines the following unloading document cleanup steps. Other specifications can define more.
>
> 1. Make disappear any `WebSocket` objects that were created by the `WebSocket()` constructor from the `Document`'s `Window` object. If this affected any `WebSocket` objects, then set `Document`'s salvageable state to false.
> 2. If the `Document`'s salvageable state is false, forcibly close any `EventSource` objects that whose constructor was invoked from the `Document`'s `Window` object.
> 3. If the `Document`'s salvageable state is false, empty the `Document`'s `Window`'s list of active timers.

Regarding [making disappear `WebSocket` objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#garbage-collection-3), the following is defined:

> If a user agent is to make disappear a `WebSocket` object (this happens when a `Document` object goes away), the user agent must follow the first appropriate set of steps from the following list:
>
> - If the WebSocket connection is not yet established
>
>   - Fail the WebSocket connection.
> - If the WebSocket closing handshake has not yet been started
>
>   - Start the WebSocket closing handshake, with the status code to use in the WebSocket Close message being `1001`.
> - Otherwise
>
>   - Do nothing.

In other words, browsers are expected to close WebSockets connections when you leave the page.

The [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) defines the `1001` status code for this situation:

> [**7.4.1.  Defined Status Codes**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4.1)
>
> Endpoints MAY use the following pre-defined status codes when sending
> a Close frame.
>
> - **`1000`**
>
> `1000` indicates a normal closure, meaning that the purpose for
> which the connection was established has been fulfilled.
>
> - **`1001`**
>
> `1001` indicates that an endpoint is "going away", such as a server
> going down or a browser having navigated away from a page.
>
> [...]

Below you will find more details regarding issues reported in Chrome and Firefox:

- [Issue 51687 - WebSocket: Send close with code 1001 on reload / tab close](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51687)
- [Bug 765738 - Race condition allows ghost WebSocket connections to live after tab closed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765738)

Comment: Please, pay attention that the question is about behavior of java ee class.

Comment: @JimJim2000 I've just added more details to my answer. Hope they are useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.websocket.Session#isOpen()` will return true if the WebSocket connection is active - i.e. capable of creating `javax.websocket.Session`. If you invoke `javax.websocket.Session#close()` on a particular `Session` and then call `javax.websocket.Session#isOpen()` on the same session, it will always return true, because the underlying WebSocket will be still active and capable of creating new `Session`. Ambiguous, is it not?

However, after you `javax.websocket.Session#close()` and then call `session.getOpenSessions().size()` you will see that the count will decrease.

In short - if WebSocket connection is active, `#isOpen()` always returns true.